# Maximum number of public keys in the ethereum universe

Tags: ether, wallets, public-key

Is there a formula to determine the maximum number of public keys (wallets) in the Ethereum universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically a wallet is an address, not a public key, and you control that wallet by having a private key that maps to the address. An address is 20 bytes (2^160 possible addresses) and a private key is 32 bytes (2^256 possible keys).

This could very well expand when sharding is introduced, since each shard will have its own account space.

Comment: I didn't know about [Sharding](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ), double thanks!